# Want to insert data in MYSQL table by user command using python programming

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert data in mysql table by user command. But i can't understand why cannot execute code. Code sample:

```
user_name= input("What is your name?:\n")
user_phone= input("What is your phone:\n")
user_city= input("Your city:\n")
myCursor.execute("insert into information(name,phone, city) values(user_name, user_phone, user_city);")
print("Insert successfully")
```

Comment: Please do not use the recipes from the answers. They will make your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use placeholders and parameter substitution instead. How exactly that looks depends a bit on the driver you use, but it always follows the pattern of the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect("Host", "Username", "Password", "Database")
cur = con.cursor()
#taken from sample displayed
user_name = input("What is your name?:\n")
user_phone = int(input("What is your phone number:\n"))
user_city = input("Your city:\n")
cur.execute("insert into information(name,phone, city) values('{}', {}, 
'{}')".format(user_name, user_phone, user_city))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: **Never** use string formatting or concatenation to put parameters into an SQL statement. *Especially* not if the values come from unprocessed user input. See what happens when you run your script and enter `c'); DROP TABLE information --` at the *Your city:* prompt. Always use the parameters or args argument of the [`execute*`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute) methods to pass parameters to your queries.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define below variables in order to use execute.

```
import cx_Oracle
DSN_TNS = cx_Oracle.makedsn(IP, PORT, SID)
DB_CRED = cx_Oracle.connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DSN_TNS)
curs = DB_CRED.cursor()
user_name= input("What is your name?:\n")
user_phone= input("What is your phone:\n")
user_city= input("Your city:\n")
sql_query = "insert into information(name,phone, city) values('{0}','{1}','{2}')".format(user_name, user_phone, user_city)
curs.execute(sql_query)
DB_CRED.commit()
DB_CRED.close()
```

Comment: **Never** use string formatting or concatenation to put parameters into an SQL statement. *Especially* not if the values come from unprocessed user input. See what happens when you run your script and enter `c'); DROP TABLE information --` at the *Your city:* prompt. Always use the parameters or args argument of the [`execute*`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.execute) methods to pass parameters to your queries.

Comment: @shmee your statement makes sense, can you please guide how to modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Especially cx_Oracle offers several ways of safe parameter substitution. Generally in DB-API 2 compliant packages, you create an SQL string with placeholders, and pass either a sequence of values or a dictionary along with the SQL string to the `execute` method. E.g. `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (:1, :2)", ('value1', 'value2'))` Have a look at the official docs I linked in my other comment and see some more elaborate examples in [this tutorial](https://learncodeshare.net/2015/06/26/insert-crud-using-cx_oracle/).

Comment: However, note that the OP is tagged with `mysql`. The cursor's paramstyle differs from driver to driver.